# Update Table (ListObject) Row Values, based on first cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update data in any table using this format:

```vb
Dim Update As String
Dim FindUpdate As Range
         
Update = Range("USER_NAME").value
        
With Sheets("Settings")
    Set FindUpdate = .Range("USERS_TABLE").Find(What:=Update, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    .Cells(FindUpdate.row, 6).value = Computer
End With
```

This code works but it requires me to put this table at the beginning of the Sheet.

I want to change values in a table **(ListObjects("USERS_TABLE"))** regardless of where it's positioned in the worksheet. Changing the range to a table's name **USERS_TABLE** did not do the trick.

Ideally I want to change the above code to:

```vb
Dim Update As String
Update = Range("USER_NAME").value ' This is a Namedrange

' declare a variables that will point to a table I want to access
dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim table_row as ListRow
Set table_row = ws.ListObject("USERS_TABLE").ListRows.**SOMETHING_TO_HELP_ACCESS_THE_TABLE_ROW_HERE**

Dim FindUpdate As Range
    
With table_row ' REPLACE SHEETS WITH TABLE_ROW

    Set FindUpdate = .**Row?**.Find(What:=Update, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        
    ' AND CAUSE IT'S A TABLE, MAYBE A COLUMN HERE?
    .**Cells(or Range)?**(FindUpdate.**row**, 6).value = Computer
            
End With
```

Comment: Eventually, this `.Cells(FindUpdate.row, 6).value = Computer` is all your sub does. Could you explain how this should work on one specific table? I mean `FindUpdateRow` is a worksheet row while 6 is a worksheet column. How do these relate to a table? Is there always only one table per worksheet? Are all of the tables starting with cell `A1`? Please add more relevant information to your post.

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 like I said, I'm trying to change this whole code to edit a table rather than a sheet... But its kind of difficult to do so, since I'm new to vba...

I have this snippet which I use to add items to a table, which works perfectly... and it's simple, straight to the point. so, I want to use the same method  to update table rows...

`
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim add_row As ListRow
    
    Set add_row = ws.ListObjects("Names_Table").ListRows.Add(1)
    
    With add_row
    
        .Range(1) = "Sample Text"
    
    End With
`

Comment: Still doesn't ring a bell. Do you maybe want to use a sub like this: `AddTableRow "NamesTable", 1, "Sample Text"`? If so, share the exact line you would want to write to get the job done?

Comment: Reason for this is that I want to put a few tables on 1 sheet for users, brands, categories, etc... I'm building a woocommerce inventory manager for at work... So if I get that update table values right, I can apply the method for all tables... create a CRUD like function

Answer (score 0):

TO @VBasic2008, sorry for the confusion, but... This is what I have... It works I can add rows using this

```
Public Sub Add_Table_Row()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim add_row As ListRow
    
    Set add_row = ws.ListObjects("Names_Table").ListRows.Add(1)
    
    With add_row
    
        .Range(3) = "Sample Text"
    
    End With

End Sub
```

I want to use the above method to update Table values, like this...

```
Public Sub Update_Table_Row()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim update_row As ListRow
    
    Set update_row = ws.ListObjects("Names_Table").ListRows ' STUCK HERE
    
    With update_row 
    
        .Range(3) = "Change This Text"
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

is it work?

Public Sub Update_Table_Row()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim update_row As ListRow

Set update_row = ws.ListObjects("Names_Table").ListRows ' STUCK HERE

With update_row 

    .Range(3) = "Change This Text"

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply... Found a simple solution to **ADD** and **UPDATE** a Table (**ListObjects.ListRow**) Row

**1. Add Table Row with values**

```
Sub Add_Product()

    ' Declare Products Database Variable
    Dim Products_Table As ListObject
    Set Products_Table = Sheets("Products").ListObjects("PRODUCT_DATABASE")

    ' Declare Add Product Variable
    Dim Product_New_Row As ListRow
    Set Product_New_Row = Products_Table.ListRows.Add(1)

    With Product_New_Row

        .Range(1) = "PRODUCTSKU01" ' 1st Column
        .Range(2) = "New Product Name" ' 2nd Column
        .Range(5) = 1000 ' 5th Column

    End With

End Sub
```

**2. Change Table Row Values**

```
Sub Update_Product()

    ' Declare Products Database Variable
    Dim Products_Table As ListObject
    Set Products_Table = Sheets("Products").ListObjects("PRODUCT_DATABASE")

    ' Declare Search Value
    Dim Find_Value As String
    Find_Value = "PRODUCTSKU01" ' 1st Column of the Products Database

    ' Declare Product Row
    Dim Product_Update_Row As Range
    Set Product_Update_Row = Products_Table.DataBodyRange.Find( _
        What:=Find_Value, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext _
    )

    ' Update Product
    With Product_Update_Row

        ' Change column # value
        .Cells(1, 2).value = "Change Product Name"

    End With

End Sub
```